# Get Live Location from user in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I need to get an updated user's location. When I send my live location to the bot, I can read latitude and longitude, but they stay constant. I see on the map how my location changes, but the bot is not able to update the coordinates.

When I sent my live location, function `getLocation` save my message and show coordinates.

```
def getLocation(bot, update, user_data):
    msg = update.message
    user_data['msg'] = msg
    user_data['id'] = update.update_id
    update.message.reply_text('lat: {}, lng: {}'.format(
        msg.location.latitude, msg.location.longitude))
```

Then when I moves, I want to know my actual coordinates with `/track` command, but it shows old coordinates.

```
def showCoordinates(bot, update, user_data):
    # I need to update location here but I don't know
    newLoc = user_data['msg']
    update.message.reply_text('lat: {}, lng: {}'.format(
        newLoc.location.latitude, newLoc.location.longitude))
```

This is my dispatcher

```
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location,
                              getLocation,
                              pass_user_data=True))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('track',
                              showCoordinates,
                              pass_user_data=True))
```

I tried with `Update(user_data['id'], edit_message=user_data['loc'])` inside the function `showCoordinates` but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `getLocation` you stored coordinates in `user_data['msg']`, then you request `newLoc` from the old `user_data['msg']` which contained previous coordinates.
You should update data variable when you moves. it's like checkin in you case.
Otherwise, new Telegram API a support a live location. please see the docs.